# Pandas Python - failed to import pandas in python

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYBqY.jpg)

I am trying to import pandas to python. But error incurred. Then,I tried to run the code after I deleted the numpy)because I thought there is some issue with the numpy. But now another error incurred(shown in the image).

Any suggestion for me? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Pandas requires numpy to work, make sure to use a package manager to install those libraries, it will handle the dependencies automatically

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there is error even when I have both numpy and pandas. Also, what is a package manager?

Comment: You want want to read [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)'s documentation

Answer (score 1):

First of all please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

**Answer to your question**:
Pandas is a Python package that provides fast, flexible, and expressive data structures designed to make working with "relational" or "labeled" data both easy and intuitive. To install you have to use pip or Anaconda. For beginners I recommend pip, here is the official documentation how to install [Official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html), [pip doc](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/). Error is telling you what was unabled to download numpy, try to import via pip [numpy pip](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try uninstalling and reinstall pandas library. If not, then try creating another python or conda environment and install it again.

Comment: I tried a few times reinstalling pandas, but it didn't help. I think I will try downloading another version of python.